# rq info showing job_id (None None):?

Tags: python, redis, python-rq, rq

Whenever we are trying to see queue info using  `rq info  -u <<redis_url>>` command, we are getting lots of extra entries like this -

```
a331d42408099f7e5ec9c5864 (None None): ?
c352af4c2385cdf320d7b74897 (None None): ?
134174815b44c44d706417eb0 (None None): ?
7b3314c8696c483b3a0a08a27 (None None): ?
15f1bb4bc78f1465076d638b5e (None None): ?
```

They do not belong to any queue and they are just hanging in there. Questions are -
*What are they?

How to clear them from redis?*

More details -
python jobs are queued in redis.
rq, version 1.5.0
python 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries you see appear to be [**zombie workers**](https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/787#issuecomment-598725121). There can be different reasons for them to show up when `rq info` is queried. One possible cause would be a job taking longer than allowed and it's horse is killed. The worker process in-turn becomes a zombie (*it sounds like a scary movie).*

The [discussion](https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/787) regarding the "zombie workers" was before the release of [v1.6.0](https://github.com/rq/rq/releases/tag/v1.6.0). To the best of my knowledge it was resolved from that point on. The latest version as of this answer is [**v1.10.1**](https://github.com/rq/rq/releases/tag/v1.10.1), and I would imagine a happy ending to this story if you could update your version to a more recent one.

Comment: very nice answer, this is what i was looking for. It make sense. Unfortunately we can not update the rq. Is there any alternate ways ( like restart the redis) to clean them? They are increasing in production.

Comment: @KoushikRoy: There are a couple of scripts ([1](https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/787#issuecomment-289239830), [2](https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/787#issuecomment-337801230)) shown within the Github discussion that you could probably adapt fairly easily to suit your needs. You could create a cron job perhaps and run the script at a regular interval to clean out the processes. I haven't tested any of the scripts mentioned, although it's likely going to be your only option since you can't update `rq`